# Updating just a single content field from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, content

I have a Task that is running through a collection of elements, moving some data from one field to another. The problem I am hitting (more and more with situations like this) is that in order to update just one field of an element, using the [recommended](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust) `BaseElementModel::setContentFromPost()` method, I have to also account for all kinds of other values to get it to validate and save.

I know you need to specify the IDs (from questions like [these](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/updating-a-single-custom-field-within-an-entry) [two](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11661/programmatically-update-entry-field)) for any relation fields that are required, which is not ideal, but not a huge issue in this case.

However, on this project I also have the Venti plugin installed, with its `Venti_EventFieldType` for dates and RRULEs, and I'm having to manually pass through a big array of any existing start/end date information into `setContentFromPost()` just so the validation for that field will pass, even though I'm doing absolutely nothing with that field.

Is there not a single way to update a single field's value, without already knowing the way data needs to be formatted for *any* other fields that might be on that `ContentModel`? Otherwise I don't see how a general-release plugin could be made that can modify existing elements, without knowing about the `setContentFromPost()`-specific data format of every possible Field Type in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience using tasks, but I often write plugin methods to move data around. Typically, I just use the EntriesService [`saveEntry`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EntriesService#saveEntry-detail) or RelationService [`saveRelation`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/RelationsService#saveRelations-detail) as needed.

Here is a sample from a recent data move:

```
    // Assign category and save entries
    foreach($unassignedEntries as $entry) {

        $success = craft()->relations->saveRelations($field, $entry, array($categoryId));

        if (!$success) {
            LogicPlugin::log('Couldn’t update entry "'.$entry->title.'"', LogLevel::Error);
        }
        else {
            LogicPlugin::log('Successfully updated entry "'.$entry->title.'"', LogLevel::Info);
        }
    }
```